# Изменение фона картинки в windows phone

Tags: windowsphone

Как изменить фон при клике?

```
<Button Click="btn_Click">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Я нашел решение  с помощью BitmapImage, но этот класс не распознаётся в Visual Studio.

Скажите, почему?

Я создавал пустой проект Windows Phone, хотя и в проекте Windows Phone Silverlight он тоже не распознаётся.

Comment: BtimapImage не распознаётся, вероятно, потому, что не открыто пространство имён Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging. Укажите его в using.

Comment: @peter Да, спасибо. Как правильно прописать путь к картинке. Я прописываю двумя способами                                                                                              1) @"C:\Users\Vlad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\changeImageBackground\changeImageBackground\Assets\fon.jpg                                                                                                   2) Assets/fon.jpg                                                                                          Оба не работают

Comment: "ms-appx:///Assets/fon.jpg"